# Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager (HAXM) installation fails

Tags: android

I'm using Android Studio and would like to install "Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager" (HAXM). Installation "silent_install -log ..." fails with:

> ```
> Property(S): VT_Not_Support = This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x). HAXM cannot be installed.
> Please refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.
> Property(S): XD_Not_Support = This computer does not support Intel Execute Disable Bit (XD) or it is disable in the BIOS. HAXM cannot be installed.
> Please refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.
> ```

But calling "silent_install -c" results:

> ```
> VT support -- yes
> NX support -- yes
> ```

I couldn't find some options in BIOS for managing XD/VT.

My laptop: "TravelMate P253-M" with intel-processor i3-3110M.

Please help !

Regards Wicki

Answer (score 0):

According to ark.intel.com your CPU does support both VT-X and XD/NX bit so things to check.

1. Can you try the regular installation for HAXM? (See if same message)
2. If you use Avast,  disable "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" under:
   Settings > Troubleshooting. Restart the PC and try to run the HAXM installation again.
3. Boot with Windows hyperV off…. 
   `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`
4. Make sure NX bit is on
   `bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn`

Comment: thank you very much ! bcdedit shows:
NX bit: OptIn,
can I reset if necessary "hypervisorlaunchtype"(missing in bcdedit) to default ?

Comment: Suggest change nx from optin to alwayson for now - to see if fixes.
And hypervisorlaunchtype can easily be set back to auto later.

Answer (score 0):

bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
  boot windows, Log: as previously + Error 1925. You do not have sufficient 
  privileges to complete this installation for all users of the machine. Log 
  on as administrator and then retry this installation.
runas /profile /user:localhost\administrator cmd
cmd: silent_install -log haxm2.log  result: HAXM is installed successfully!
but messages "VT_Not_Support = This computer does not support ..." as previously !

then I have uninstalled haxm, bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto,
boot windows, runas ... see above

Many thanks for codecats !
Regards Wicki